# Send ICMP Echo Request

Tags: python

The code:

```
ICMP_HEADER = b'x08\x00\xF7x00\x00\x00\x00'
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.getprotobyname("icmp"))
```

Now what do I do to send this echo request? I'm trying to figure out what port I send to but resources say I don't send to a specific port. And the bind/ connect methods require a port number.

Edit: I tried his suggestion as such:

```
ICMP_HEADER = b'x08\x00\xF7x00\x00\x00\x00'
ipadd = socket.gethostbyname('www.google.com')
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.getprotobyname("icmp"))
sock.sendto(ICMP_HEADER, (ipadd, 0))
reply = sock.recv(1024)
print(reply)
```

Maybe I did it wrong? The socket times out.

Comment: I believe you just pass anything into `sendto` for the port number and it's ignored for RAW.

Comment: sendto requires an address parameter and the address parameter is a tuple of ipv4 address and port number... Edit: Oh sorry, let me try this.

Comment: Take a look at this GitHub repo: https://gist.github.com/pklaus/856268